# Datastax astra : max columns number and lists size

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax-astra

As lists in Cassandra is translated into dynamic columns (please correct me if I am wrong) and Astra free plan puts a limit on columns number per table.
So my question is : dose this implies a limit on list | map | set sizes.
My second question is regarding to the free plan of Astra because it's not clear for me and I am wondering do I get 25$ of usage quota once for my entire usage or I get 25$ every new month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists/maps/sets are represented as a **separate cells** under the hood, but they are represented as a single column on the CQL level, so you should be good.  But you may get restriction on the number of items in the collection.

Regarding pricing - the [official page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/pricing-and-billing.html#_plan_selection) says:

> Each plan includes a $25.00 free credit **per month**. The $25 credit is good for approximately 30 million reads, 5 million writes, and 40GB of storage per month.